# Using csound from inside python

Tags: python-2.7, csound

Is it possible to use Csound from inside python for live-electronic music tasks? Can anyone give a hint of how can this be done if possible?

Answer (score 5):

Csound has an API with Python bindings available for facilitating writing music and music applications with Python. Some tutorial examples for using Csound within Python are available in the csoundAPIExamples project here:

https://github.com/csound/csoundAPI_examples/tree/master/python

Besides csnd6, which comes with most installations of Csound or is available within package repos on Linux, is a newer ctypes-based binding called ctcsound:

https://github.com/fggp/ctcsound/

Comment: I just found this interesting paper : 
http://www.csounds.com/journal/issue14/realtimeCsoundPython.html